# sequelize couldnt save array of objects into table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I sent this request which is an array of objects from reactjs app to nodejs(sequelize,mysql)backend

```
{  
   "Qusetion":"new question",
   "Qusetiontype":"AddedAnswers",
   "Qusetionanswers":[  
      {  
         "QuestionAnswer":"a1"
      },
      {  
         "QuestionAnswer":"a2"
      }
   ],
    "Surveyid":"9fe96b40-7704-11e9-b46f-3f2c20a71682"
}
```

the nodejs script

```
 QuestionAnswer.create(req.body.Qusetionanswers.map(Answer=>{
        Qusetionanswer=Answer.QuestionAnswer,
        QuestionId=qid
    })       
    ).then(res=>{console.log(res)}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
```

**My Problem:** I got below error msg in postman when trying to send new question I searched and found that create not accept an array of objects and nothing else.so any help thanks in advance

```
{
    "message": "this.build(...).save is not a function"
}
```

Comment: half of my problem solved by using bulkCreate to insert an array of objects but the other half is I want to insert id with this bulk which is not attached to that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try it likes this. Creating one after one. Or are you trying to archive anything else?

```
  req.body.Questionanswers.map(answer => {
    QuestionAnswer.create({
        Qusetionanswer: answer.QuestionAnswer,
        QuestionId: qid
      }).then(res => {console.log(res);}).catch(err => {console.log(err);}
    );
  });
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined...yes i put inside then...i used `bulkcreate` and its worked but couldnt insert `QuestionId` with this array @Montezuma

Comment: When Qusetionanswers is undefined something else is wrong. Sounds like a bad request.

Comment: if you have an array of objects it's better to use `blukCreate`  but for this problem, because I want to insert another value with that array I used @Montezuma solution.